# Preventing two conflicting Firefox extensions from being installed at the same time

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I built two separate Firefox extensions which are fundamentally incompatible with each other. The incompatibility is *by design*, as it would be totally unlogical for a user to install both. While I can stress out in the doc that both shouldn't be used at the same time, I don't trust the user to read the doc, and I'm looking for a way that one extension could detect the presence of the other and either disable itself or the other one (ideally while popping an error message).

Is there a way for an extension to be aware of the presence of another extension? I know it's possible for an extension [to specify it depends on another one](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Extension_Manager:Extension_Dependencies), but what I need is the exact opposite, a way for an extension to specify it conflicts with another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firefox Addon Development : Detecting non-compatible addons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733357/firefox-addon-development-detecting-non-compatible-addons)